Allure pattern only works for annotations (@tms , @issue) but does not work for Java API Allure.link("Website", "https://dev.example.com/");
When using the @tms or @issue annotations, the allure.link.tms.pattern and allure.link.issue.pattern works.
However, when using the JAva API, it seems this patterns are not used.
Is that intented ?
It would be nice that this feature also works on Java API.
ex :
 @Issue("AUTH-123")
    @TmsLink("TMS-456")
    void testAuthentication() {

=> create properly the report with the enhanced link using allure.link.tms.pattern
Allure.tms("TMS-456", "TMS-456");

=> doesn't create the report with enhanced link.
